# Steam Restriction

Tags: steam

I purchased and redeemed multiple $5 steam gift cards and it said a month ago that I need to wait 30 days before I can use the community market. It's been 30 days and I am still restricted...

> Steam is having trouble using your browser's cookie.
>
> The account must have a successful purchase older than 30 days,  but
>   not older than a year. You also cannot have recently changed  your
>   account's password.
>
> This restriction will expire in 29 days, 23 hours and 59 minutes.

It's been like this all month and hasn't gone down. What do I need to do, to remove the restriction?

Comment: First off you'll have to follow the directions... you need to have a game purchased that is older than 30 days, but not older than a year. Have you bought a game yet?

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to... does it matter on the price? Could I buy a game for $1 and it will still work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to follow the directions that the message is giving you. Specifically:

```
The account must have a successful purchase older than 30 days, 
but not older than a year. You also cannot have recently changed 
your account's password.
```

This is to prevent fraud within the platform. I can't imagine why you would want to purchase things from the Community Market without actually purchasing any games first, but that's your deal.

You do not need to purchase a full AAA $60 game for it to count.

[image]

You will still need to wait the 30 days to use the cards though.

Comment: It's for TF2 which is F2P, I found a $0.29, and that will do?

Comment: Again, any price game will do.

Comment: If it works out, I would appreciate you marking this as the answer! :)

Comment: I think it may have to be a $5 game, unless they changed it.

Comment: @Aequitas Yep I checked with Steam's policy, answer has been edited.